# Make Spring form:select searchable by two parameters

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu (Product Type):

[image]

Generated by the Spring MVC code (Google MDL fluff removed)

```
<form:select path="productType" required="required">
    <form:option value="" label="" />
    <form:options items="${availableProductTypesForAdd}" />
</form:select>
<label for="productType">Product Type</label>
```

The `${availableProductTypesForAdd}` is loaded into the model by the controller like so:

```
HashMap<String, String> availableProductTypesForAdd = new HashMap<>();

availableProductTypesForAdd.put("191", "191 - Table");
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("201", "201 - Chair");
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("230", "230 - Desk");
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("232", "232 - Monitor");

model.put("availableProductTypesForAdd", availableProductTypesForAdd);
```

If you printed `${availableProductTypesForAdd}` to the screen it would look like:

`{191=191 - Table, 201=201 - Chair, 230=230 - Desk, 232=232 - Monitor}`

Users filling out the form know one of two things: (1) the product key (191, 201, etc) or (2) the product name (table, chair, etc).

- Some users are not familiar with the keys so they need to search by the product name.
- Some users are familiar with the keys and prefer the more expeditious route of typing the key.

I would like to make the drop down selectable via keyboard by both of these. i.e., when the user tabs to this field, they can type "201" or "chair" on the keyboard and it will select the right item on the list.

Right now, the list is only searchable by the type code (191, 201, etc) because the displayed string starts with the code.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use something like Select2 to enhance the component? https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage. The default setup will search on whether the value contains the search param (rather than starts with) which looks like what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately that requires the user to click the box with the mouse. If you tab to the box then the type-to-select does not work with select2.

Comment: Tab + space bar/enter  to start typing. I would imagine you could also capture focus event to auto show text box?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and likely most preferable would be to use some replacement of standard *select* as it's not much customizable.

You can try ['Chosen' jQuery plugin](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). This will require external js and css. However, seems to fully satisfy you requirements without pain and workarounds.

Simply **4 extra lines in your jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form id="form" method="post" modelAttribute="form" action="/submit2">
    <form:select path="productType" required="required" >
        <form:option value="" label="" />
        <form:options items="${availableProductTypesForAdd}" />
    </form:select>
    <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" />
</form:form>

<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script>$(function(){ $('select').chosen(); })</script>
```

**and here you are:**
*(it works like a charm in more or less fresh chrome, safari, and FF on OSX)*

[image: 'Choosen' in action]

```js
$(function(){
    $('select').chosen();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/docsupport/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="/submit2" method="post">
    <select id="productType" name="productType" required="required">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="232">232 - Monitor</option><option value="310">310 - Bad</option><option value="201">201 - Chair</option><option value="555">555 - Sofa</option><option value="191">191 - Table</option><option value="999">999 - Bookcase</option><option value="618">618 - Armchair</option><option value="230">230 - Desk</option>
    </select>
    <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

Also you can take a look at [HTML Data List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<form:form id="form" method="post" modelAttribute="form" action="/submit">
    <form:input path="productType" list="productTypes" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
        <datalist id="productTypes">
            <c:forEach items="${availableProductTypesForAdd}" var="productType">
                <option value="${productType.key}">${productType.value}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </datalist>
    <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</form:form>
```

[image: search anywhere]

You can even remove keys from options as it shows and searches in both value and text

```
HashMap<String, String> availableProductTypesForAdd = new HashMap<>();
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("191", "Table");
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("201", "Chair");
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("230", "Desk");
availableProductTypesForAdd.put("232", "Monitor");
```

[image: search anywhere]
[image: search anywhere]

However, it is not as strict as *select* and allows to input anything not limited by options (it's by nature kind of suggestions, that's why *autocomplete* is *off*)

But if you are fine with some tiny js, you can add some extra logic to cover this gap, here is one of the options (cleans out input if it does not match one of the options):

```
<script>
(function() {
    function verify() {
        var input = document.getElementById("productType");
        var o = [].map.call(input.list.options, opt => opt.value);
        var opts = o.reduce((result, v) => (result[v.toUpperCase()] = v, result), {});
        var value = input.value.toUpperCase();
        if (!opts[value]) {
            input.value = '';
            return false;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("productType").addEventListener("focusout", verify);
    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("focusout", verify);
})();
</script>
```

---

Basically you can slightly improve default . But only if you are fine with this search not fully working when menu is opened (because that menu is not accessible from js because it's OS specific and seems to not even be a part of html).

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form id="form" method="post" modelAttribute="form" action="/submit2">
    <form:select path="productType" required="required" >
        <form:option value="" label="" />
        <form:options items="${availableProductTypesForAdd}" />
    </form:select>
    <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit" />
</form:form>

<script>
(function() {
    var lastKeysForSearchNumber = 7; // tune # of keys entered to keep
    var lastKeys = [];
    var select = document.querySelector('[name=productType]');
    function search(e) {
        if (e.key.match(/^\w$/i)) {
            lastKeys.push(e.key);
            if (lastKeys.length > lastKeysForSearchNumber) {
                lastKeys.shift();
            }
            select.value = bestMatch(select.options, lastKeys.join(''));
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function bestMatch(options, input) {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
                if (options[j].text.match(new RegExp(input.substring(i), 'i'))) { // contains ignore case
                    return options[j].value;
                }
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
    select.addEventListener("keydown", search);
})();
</script>
```

The idea here is to store last 7 (or whatever) keys and check every option if it contains as much as possible.

[image]

This could require some tuning and/or some adaptation for specific browsers (IE?) 
Here is snipped for that, try it out:

```js
(function() {
    var lastKeysSorSearchNumber = 7;
    var lastKeys = [];
    var select = document.querySelector('[name=productType]');
    function search(e) {
        if (e.key.match(/^\w$/i)) {
            lastKeys.push(e.key);
            if (lastKeys.length > lastKeysSorSearchNumber) {
                lastKeys.shift();
            }
            select.value = bestMatch(select.options, lastKeys.join(''));
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function bestMatch(options, input) {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
                if (options[j].text.match(new RegExp(input.substring(i), 'i'))) {
                    return options[j].value;
                }
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
    select.addEventListener("keydown", search);
})();
```

```html
<form id="form" action="/submit2" method="post">
    <select id="productType" name="productType" required="required">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="310">310 - Bad</option><option value="201">201 - Chair</option><option value="2324">2324 - Monitor</option><option value="555">555 - Sofa</option><option value="191">191 - Table</option><option value="999">999 - Bookcase</option><option value="618">618 - Armchair</option><option value="230">230 - Desk</option>
    </select>
    <label for="productType">Product Type</label>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get it fully functioning, but I gave you the bounty because of your obvious labor over this answer.

Comment: just wonder why chosen doesn’t work for you? is it conflicting with something? maybe you can post final html?

Comment: Mostly time. Swamped with work. Apparently the bounty is only active for 7 days and then it's gone forever lol. So I had to preemptively award the bounty. I'll work the problem later.

Comment: I see, good luck then. Thank for not allowing bounty just go nowhere, lol.